# PySide TextEditor

Tags: python, qt, pyside

I want to incorporate a lightweight text editor into my python/pyside program. It should be able to do basic stuff like show line numbers and syntax highlighting.

Is there a Module/Widget for that, or would I have to make one myself?

Comment: Look at [Code Editor Example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/widgets-codeeditor.html)+[Syntax Highlighter Example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/richtext-syntaxhighlighter.html) to see how to make one yourself.

Answer (score 4):

Try QScintilla, it's the component used by the Eric IDE

http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/qscintilla

Comment: I thought that was only for PyQt, not PySide

Comment: Yeah, I saw that, but how does it work? Do you need to get the regular QScintilla and then that just binds it to pyside?

Comment: I'm sure that after 4 years he figured it out by himself :P

Comment: You never know @LtWorf ;-)
I have struggled a lot with QScintilla myself some time ago. I almost gave up because documentation is lacking. But I found someone who is doing the effort to write proper beginners documentation. That's why I'm trying to share this website with as many people as possible. I believe it can help out newbies on this software :-)

Answer (score 1):

Just looking for this myself:
[PySide QSyntaxHighlighter](https://deptinfo-ensip.univ-poitiers.fr/ENS/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QSyntaxHighlighter.html#detailed-description)